# Не получаю асинхронные ответы от сервера

Tags: php, ajax

Мне необходимо отправлять `ajax`-запросы в один `php`-обработчик. Мои запросы идут параллельно, как и должно быть, а вот ответы от сервера приходят последовательно. Я знаю об ограничении браузера на 6 одновременных запросов. На `centos` у меня стоит `apache`. Я думаю, что возможно мне надо изменить конфигурационный файл сервера, чтобы ответы оправлялись асинхронно, но я не уверена.
В качестве простой модели моей ситуации привожу код. В реальной задаче я не использую `sleep()`, но каждый мой запрос выполняется около 5 секунд. Таким образом мне необходимо, чтобы 6 запросов выполнялись за 5-7 секунд, а не 30.
Код скрипта:

```
<script>
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    $.get("/ajax1.php")
        .done(function (res) {
            if (res != "") {
                $area=$(".workarea-center");
                $area.html($area.html()+res);
            }
        });

}
```

Код обработчика `ajax1.php`:

```
sleep(5);
echo ("111");
```

Comment: Вы сессии в своем скрипте на сервере используете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно, невозможность получения асинхронных ответов от сервера связана с использованием сессий в php коде.

Пример

js+html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
    $.get("test2.php?i="+i)
        .done(function (res) {
            if (res != "") {
                $area=$(".workarea-center");
                $area.html($area.html()+res);
            }
        });

}
</script>

<div class="workarea-center"></div>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
sleep(5);
$i = $_GET['i'];
$j = isset($_SESSION['j']) ? $_SESSION['j'] : 1;
echo '.'.($j * $i).'.';
$_SESSION['j'] = $i;
```

Поведение скриптов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй вариант с обработкой сессии в самом начале скрипта и ее закрытие через session_write_close().

Измененный test2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$i = $_GET['i'];
$j = isset($_SESSION['j']) ? $_SESSION['j'] : 1;
$_SESSION['j'] = $i;
session_write_close();
sleep(5);
echo '.'.($j * $i).'.';
```

Поведение скриптов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо, дело было именно в сессиях, буду разбираться