# При старте сессии в нескольких файла, другие файлы не откроются, пока не отработает каждый скрипт

Tags: php, сессия

Такой вопрос интересный.

Есть 2 файла
file1.php
file2.php

Содержимое

```
//file1.php
<?php
session_start();

$time = time() + 3;// Ждем 3 секунды, а потом отдаем ответ
while( time() <= $time ){}
echo 'okay';


//file2.php
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Открыт file2.php';
```

Когда я открываю файл в браузере file1.php, он запускает цикл, и  ждет его обработку, после чего выдает строку 'okay';

И в этот же момент когда file1 в обработке, я пытаюсь открыть file2.php, и тут самое интересное, file2.php не открывается, пока не выполнится цикл в file1.

Если убрать

> session_start();

в file1 ИЛИ в file2, тогда file2.php открывается без ожидания завершения цикла в file1.

**Вопрос**: Почему так происходит при старте сессии в обеих файлах, и как решить эту проблему, чтобы file2.php можно было открыть без ожидания завершения цикла в file1.php?...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454949/186083

Comment: @Visman то, что нужно, спасибо, можете в ответ написать

Answer (score 1):

Если мы знаем, что в сессии не надо ничего изменять, мы можем просто прочитать ее переменные и сразу закрыть, чтобы не блокировать файл сессии, который может понадобиться другим сессиям.

В этом случае `file1.php` может выглядеть так:

```
<?php
session_start([
    'read_and_close'  => true
]);

$time = time() + 3;// Ждем 3 секунды, а потом отдаем ответ
while( time() <= $time ){}
echo 'okay';
```

Данный пример относится к PHP7, где в функции `session_start()` имеется параметр `options`. 
Для более младших версий PHP в данном случае для решения проблемы надо использовать функцию `session_name`, позволяющую установить имя текущей сессии.

Comment: Изменять в сессии нужно будет данные, не только читать...